# Minimax problem where a combination of Minimize and Maximize gives no result at all

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum, maximize

I rarely use Mathematica, but I usually do not have any problem with simple commands like `Minimize` or `Maximize`. I have find to maximum over $0<a\le\tfrac14$ *of* the minimum over $c<p\le\tfrac12$ for some very small positive constant $c$ of the following expression:

$$\frac{p \log\frac{p}{p+a}+(1-p) \log\frac{1-p}{1-(p+a)}}{a^2}\,.$$

Hence, I tried to use `Maximize[{Minimize[{(p Log[(p/(p+a))]+(1-p) Log[((1-p)/(1-(p+a)))])/a^2, 0<a<=1/4 && 1/100<p<=1/2},{p}],  0<a<=1/4 && 1/100<p<=1/2}, {a}]`, but I do not any result at all.

Could you please explain the reason of the missing output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 13.3 on Windows 10 using a fresh kernel,

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := NMinimize[{(p Log[(p/(p + a))] + (1 - 
      p) Log[((1 - p)/(1 - (p + a)))])/a^2, 1/100 < p <= 1/2}, p] 
f[0.1]
```

> `{2.00447, {p -> 0.433393}}`

```
NMaximize[{f[a]//First, a > 0 && a <= 1/4}, a]
```

> `{2.02875, {a -> 0.25}}`

```
f[0.25]
```

> `{2.02875, {p -> 0.334294}}`

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a closed-form symbolic solution for

```
Minimize[{(p Log[(p/(p + a))] + (1 - p) Log[((1 - p)/(1 - (p + a)))])/a^2, 0 < p < 1/2}, p]
```

So creating a table of minimum values for values of `a` might shed some insight.

```
t = Table[Flatten[{a, 
  FindMinimum[{(p Log[(p/(p + a))] + (1 - p) Log[((1 - p)/(1 - (p + a)))])/a^2, 0 < p < 1/2},
  {p, 0.4}]}], {a, 1/1000, 1/4, 1/1000}];
ListPlot[t[[All, {1, 2}]], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18, Black] &) /@ {"a", ""}]
```

[image]

So it looks like the maximum of the minimums is achieved when $ a=1/4$.  That happens to correspond to the last value in the table `t`:

```
t[[250]]
(* {1/4, 2.02875, p -> 0.334294} *)
```

Comment: How can we know that there are no pairs $(a,p)$ corresponding to a smaller than $2$ for the evaluated function?

Comment: There is something I do not understand: if $p$ is set to be equal to $0.334294$ then the maximum of the resulting (*monotonically decreasing*) function is attained when  $a\to 0$, giving a limit value equal to $\frac{1}{2p-2p^2}$, right? This value is higher than $2.02875$.

Comment: A contour plot with the table of minimum values of $p$ for a given $a$ might be convincing:  `t=Table[Flatten[{a,p/. FindMinimum[{(p Log[(p/(p + a))]+(1-p) Log[((1-p)/(1 -(p+a)))])/a^2,0<p<1/2}, {p,0.4}][[2]]}], {a,1/1000,1/4,1/1000}];Show[ContourPlot[(p Log[(p/(p+a))]+(1-p) Log[((1-p)/(1-(p+a)))])/a^2, {a,0,1/4}, {p,1/100,1/2}, Contours -> {2.05, 2.1, 2.15, 2.2, 2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.04},
ContourShading -> None, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"a", "p"}],
 ListPlot[t, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red], ListPlot[{{1/4, 0.334294}}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.02]}}]]
`.

Comment: Thank you JimB !

Comment: Feel free to un-accept this somewhat roundabout answer for another that's more direct.